# Need multiple bootstrap carousels on same page or same site, but they need to be different dimensions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, height, width, carousel

Using Bootstrap. For example 1 would be h380 x w600, another h285 x w450m and so on. I am newbie and need actual HTML, JS, and CSS.

I have researched and only found solutions for placing multiple same size carousels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are carousels with different sizes: **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/wqpzPN)** or run the snippet below.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

h1,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

h1,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 638px) {
  h1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row1">
    <h1>400x400</h1>
    <div class="bd-example">
      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/400/400" alt="400x400" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>400x400</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/400/400" alt="400x400" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>400x400</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/400" alt="400x400" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>400x400</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row2">
    <div class="bd-example">
      <h1>600x600</h1>
      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions2" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions2" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/600/600" alt="600x600" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>600x600</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/600/600" alt="600x600" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>600x600</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placekitten.com/g/600/600" alt="600x600" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>600x600</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions2" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row3">
    <h1>250x250</h1>
    <div class="bd-example">
      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions3" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions3" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions3" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/250/250" alt="250x250" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>250x250</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/250/250" alt="250x250" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>250x250</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placekitten.com/g/250/250" alt="250x250" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>250x250</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions3" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/rosskevin/popper.js/feature-allow-text-html-node/src/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Update**

To make it autoplay with Bootstrap 3, update your JQuery code at the bottom of your html so it looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#firstCarousel').carousel({interval: 2000});
  $('#secondCarousel').carousel({interval: 2000});
});
</script>
```

Note: `2000` represents 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds). You can change the speed of each carousel by assigning each one a different number.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, however, I need 2 carousels, different heights and widths. As stated, I am newbie and do not understand modals. Sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: @Bazaboo I see - sorry I misunderstood. - I updated my answer above. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: ok! got 2 carousels, different sizes, but they do not autoplay.

Comment: Here is link to test page: http://www.artandsoulgraphics.com/Clients/FostersNew/stackcarousel3.asp

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't realize you were using Bootstrap 3. You can just add intervals to your `carousel` methods in your `<script>` tags. You can set the intervals to different milliseconds to assign the autoplay speed for each carousel. I've posted an update in my answer that you can use at the bottom of your HTML (just replace the `<script>` tags at line 90 with the code in the update, and it will autoplay.

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row carousel">
  <div id="firstCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item item active">
        <div class="carousel-item-content">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item item second-item">
      <div class="carousel-item-content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#firstCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#firstCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row carousel">
  <div id="secondCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item item active">
        <div class="carousel-item-content">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item item second-item">
      <div class="carousel-item-content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#secondCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#secondCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#firstCarousel').carousel();
  $('#secondCarousel').carousel();
});
```

in CSS you can then change height and width of your carousels by using their id

```
#firstCarousel{
  width: 600px;
  height: 380px;
}
#secondCarousel{
  width: 450px;
  height: 285px;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I will try it. I did come up with a brainstorm workaround - I created a new css file for a specific page with just the carousel css and modified that. Then included that css file in the page. It works, however, I am sure it is not the "correct" way to handle this. Also, it does not address different size carousels on same page....Will let you know results of your kind workaround!

Comment: This did not seem to work. both carousels are the same size and they bounce up and down the page